# Select values from multiple tables where certain value is zero

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two soccer-themed tables. One having all the players and a second one having their IDs, if they scored a goal. There is a value for an own goal which is 1 if true and 0 if false.

I want to select the last name of every player as well as the total number of scored goals. If a player didn't score a goal, the result should still show the player, but, for goals, a zero.

```
SELECT LastName, COUNT(Goal.Player_ID) "Goals"
FROM Player
LEFT OUTER JOIN Goal ON Player.Player_ID = Goal.Player_ID
GROUP BY LastName
ORDER BY "Goals" DESC;
```

While this works just fine, I only want to show tuples that either **didn't score a goal** or players that **scored a goal that isn't an own goal**.

Let me paraphrase: I want to select **all** players, including those that didn't score a goal, but **if they did** I only want to count the goals that **aren't own goals**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the ownGoal validation to the ON clause:

```
SELECT LastName, COUNT(Goal.Player_ID) "Goals"
FROM Player
LEFT OUTER JOIN Goal ON Player.Player_ID = Goal.Player_ID AND Goal.ownGoal = 0
GROUP BY LastName
ORDER BY "Goals" DESC;
```